# Is there a syntax to add echo statements to windows makefiles?

Tags: windows, makefile

The subject says it all:  Is there a syntax to add echo statements to windows makefiles?

```
some_target: $(dependencies)
<tab>echo Building some_target
<tab>cl .........
```

Comment: Your code should work. Where’s the problem?

Comment: I think my problem came from a path misdirection.  Another make had gotten into the path before the one I needed.  Also has to do with using `make` instead of `nmake`   Mea culpa.